# Webdesign: PNG-Image width limitations

Tags: png, slideshow

I want to make a kind of slideshow based on scrolling the webpage.

My problem is that I have an image width of 78720x1015px in png-format.
The width of the image is determined by one single image of 1920px which is 41 times arranged next to each other. - It should be like a cartoon where an image moves by 100% (margin: -100%) and generates a feeling of a movie.

However, this results in an image width of 1920px x 41pics = 78720px.

This is of an enormous width, but what I am wondering about is that the filesize is only 975kB which is in my opinion not that big!? - However, somehow it takes a very long time to load the picture in the Webbrowser and the image is not of such quality as in my ImageViewer on Desktop.

Question 1: What do I have to consider when dealing with such a big image-width? What are the limits?

Question 2: Is there a better way make such kind of a slideshow? - Consider that the sliding itself shouldn't be visible. It should be like a movie based on about 40 pictures.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

PNG compresses very well, especially if it's a cartoon like you say that may use only a limited number of colours.

However, when loaded into memory, the device must load all that pixel data into RAM to display it. That's almost 80 million pixels in your case, which would be around 320Mb of uncompressed data. This is probably why the browser is struggling, and especially so if you're using `margin` to move it around as that requires a full re-draw of the image.

You may have better results with `transform`, as this should use hardware acceleration and also avoids the reflow part of a redraw since transforms don't affect page layout.

But the better solution would be to break it down into individual images. Have your code load in the next image, scroll it across, then load the next while scrolling and unload the one that's now off-screen to provide a relatively seamless view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!Could you explain the last point in other words?! - What I

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But, can you explain the last point in other words?! - If I understand it correctly the images would be loaded separately while scrolling? - But wouldn't it lead to the same problem again, while scrolling faster? It would take also a big amount of time loading each image, or am I wrong!?

Comment: @dramen The problem with your pseudo animation with a single giant image is that the whole image must decoded and held in memory (as a raw image). Breaking into individual images should help because each image woud be decoded as needed (and the memory released when not needed)